# If value is greater than x select all values from list until value is greater than y. Make all other values 0

Tags: python, list, loops

I would like to loop through a list of values. If there is a value greater than 3, then select all the following values while the value is greater or equal than 1 (or stop before it drops lower than 1). The rest of the values in the list should be zero until another value down the list is greater than 3 and the process repeats itself.

Example:
If I have the following list:

```
l = [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3]
```

I would like to get get the following:

```
o = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]
```

So far I managed to get all values greater that 3 and the rest 0, but I don't know how to integrate the other conditon:

```
l = [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3] 
o = [0] * len(l)
for index in range(len(l)):
    if l[index] > 3:
        o[index] = l[index]
    else:
        o[index] = 0
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately htis is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Comment: Done! Added my code so far, hope this is better, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a flag to control which values to let through.
Also, I would use a generator:

```
def a_filter(items, on=3, off=1):
    through = False
    for item in items:
        if item > on:
            through = True
        elif item < off:
            through = False
        yield item if through else 0
        if item <= off:
            through = False


l = [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3]
o = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]
print(l)
# [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3]
print(o)
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]
print(list(a_filter(l)))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]

print(o == list(a_filter(l)))
# True
```

Comment: Wow! it works! Thank you so much for your answer, I didn't know you could use yield instead of return and definitely need to read more on using flags. :D Thanks again!

Comment: @agus Read up on what `yield` does, otherwise you will probably run into problems. `yield` is for the definition of so-called `generators`. For "normal" functions you should use `return`. PS: If norok2's answer was helpful then consider "upvoting" or "accepting".

Comment: @Timus, thanks for the heads up, I realize generators is something I haven't covered yet. Accepted norok2's answer. Thank you for your help!